# jQuery Isotope with hash-history

Tags: jquery, hash, history, jquery-isotope

[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) is incredible, but it doesn't work with my browser's back-button which is a real shame. Everything about the plugin is fluid, except this.

There are a number of plugins that offer this feature ([here's one](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/#documentation)), but they seem to be geared towards loading static HTML content. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Except what? Why is your browser's back button not working? What are you expecting to see that is not happening?

Comment: Please see the [open issue on hash history and Isotope](https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues//3).

Comment: I'm only using the filtering option for the project in question, other options like sortBy and layoutMode aren't user-changable. You mention there was a hacky approach for your Masonry project, so I'll give that a shot as it does everything I need it to. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I celebrated too soon ;) It's a step in the right direction but still doesn't support the back button. I guess "bookmark-able" is the word. (http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/filtering-hashes.html#red)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. See [Isotope: Hash history demo](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/hash-history.html) and [Isotope: Hash history with jQuery BBQ docs](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/hash-history-jquery-bbq.html)